# Accordion-like one-element expanding component in jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, accordion, expander

I need to implement an expanding/collapsing box in jQuery UI. When collapsed, only the box header would show. When expanded, the header+contents would show.

What I need to do is very close to jQuery UI one-element accordion with alwaysOpen=false (the same property is called "collapsible" in document, but in practice with jQuery 1.3.2 and jQuery UI 1.6rc6 it seems to be alwaysOpen):

```
$('.myAccordion').accordion({
    header: 'h3'
    , alwaysOpen: false
});
```

There is one problem: **I need the expanding/collapsing to happen only when clicking on the triangle on the left, not when clicking the whole header.**

An additional requirement is that I would like to use the jQuery UI default UI styles and not implement my own stylesheet, so that I could roll new styles with themeRoller if need be. The accordion styles in jQuery UI (including the arrows in the header) are very nicely suited for this purpose.

Now, I have two options:

1) configure the Accordion widget so that only the triangle responds to expand/collapse events. I need the clicks on the rest of the header to be basically ignored.

2) implement my own widget, using accordion styles as base.

I would rather do 1), but I am having a hard time figuring out how to make only the arrow respond to click events.

So, as for the actual question, how would you do this?

Comment: You can do this simply with jQuery without the According UI plugin. Is that something you'd like as an answer?

Comment: The Accordion UI plugin makes the whole header for an element clickable. I would like only the triangle to be clickable, not the whole header.

Comment: ... ugh, re-read the question. Yes, doing without Accordion UI is fine, I'm looking for an example of how to do that easily and reusing the UI styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, turns out it's easy to accomplish this with the accordion widget itself. Just set the accordion up this way:

```
$('.myAccordion').accordion({
    header: 'h3'
    , alwaysOpen: false
    , event: 'click'
});

$('.myAccordion h3 a').click(function() {
    return false;
})
```

Although it's bad usability practice since the click target area is so small, but well, it answers the question I posted.

Answer (score 1):

I did it like that:

```
$('.accordion').accordion({
  header: '.accordion-header',
  collapsible: true
});
```